# Django multistep form

Tags: django, forms

I have a multi-step form that is 3 steps but it has 4 forms. In the first form, the user has to choose from two choices. The user's first form choices will determine the next form that will be displayed.
The first form template.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>

    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}

    {% if form.customer_choices == 'commercial' %}
    <form action="{% url 'datacollector:step2aformview' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    {% else %}

    <form action="{% url 'datacollector:step2bformview' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    {% endif %}

    {% endblock %}
    
</body>
</html>
```

form.py

```
from .models import CustomerInfo, CustomerDocument 
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms



CUSTOMER_CHOICES = [
    ('commercial', 'Commercial'),
    ('private', 'Private'),
]

class CustomerTypeForm(forms.Form):
    customer_chioces = forms.CharField(label="Customertype", widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=CUSTOMER_CHOICES))
    
   
#Commercial customer information
class CustomerInfoForm1(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerInfo
        fields = "__all__"

#Private customer information
class CustomerInfoForm2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerInfo
        fields = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'street', 'house', 'zip1', 'city']
        

class CustomerDocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerDocument
        fields = ['document']
```

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from datacollector.forms import  CustomerTypeForm, CustomerInfoForm1, CustomerInfoForm2, CustomerDocumentForm
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect



# Create your views here.

def step1formview(request):
    initial = {'customer_chioces': request.session.get('customer_chioces', None), }    
    form = CustomerTypeForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['customer_choices'] = form.cleaned_data['customer_choices']
            if form.customer_choices == 'commercial':
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('datacollector:step2aformview'))
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('datacollector:step2bformview'))
           
    return render(request, 'forms/CustomerTypeForm.html', {'form': form})
```

If the user chooses any of the two options in the first form, it will return the same form in the next step. It was suppose to bring out different forms base on the users options in the first form

Answer (score 0):

Well, you actually have a typo here:

```
{% if form.customer_choices == 'commercial': %}
```

redundant semicolon `:`

Try to remove it

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed it. it showing no error but the code is not working as it should

Comment: @obodomauzonduvincent please update the question - desribing what exactly is not working

Comment: It's a multistep form where the first form will ask the user to choose from two choices. The next form to be displayed is dependent on the user's choice. Those are the views, template, and forms.py. it all works but the problem is if the user chooses any of the two choices in the first form it will return the same form. The returned form are supposed to be different.